# F(x,y) - F(x0,y0) = 0 for (x,y) -> (x0,y0) - But F is not continuous in (0,0) - Why? What does it mean?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have the piecewise function

Which for all (x,y)(0,0) $f(x,y) = {(x^2*y)/{(x^4}+y^2)}$ and we define $f(0,0) = 0$.

I have been taught, that in order to prove that a function is continuous in its domain, we must show that

a) $lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (x_0,y_0)} f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)=\epsilon(x-x_0,y-y_0) \rightarrow 0$

Which I interpret to mean, that there are no "bumps" between an arbitrary (x,y) and the function value at $(x_0,y_0)$ as we get infinitesimally close.

But in the special case of our previously defined f, the equation a) holds.

At the same time, as we approach (0,0) in the form of a parabola $f(x,x^2)$ i.e all the points where $y=x^2$, the value of $f(x,x^2)=1/2$ is a constant.

I have from my lecture notes, that this means, that $f(x,y)$ isn't continous in (0,0) but why? What exactly am I supposed to interpret from this?

I have so far thought about this:

Since we're never actually approaching (0,0), it is not continuous in (0,0). That is to say, that our epsilon function $\epsilon(x-x_0,y-y_0)$ for $y=x^2$ doesn't approach 0 as $lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (x0,y0)}$ it just simply is (0,0) at that point.

Furthermore, I have taken it to mean, that it is still continuous in all other points than (0,0), as these are still approached when the two point-sets approach eachother. Which technically doesn't contradict with my understanding of a), which proves the continuity in the function's "true" domain.

But it is still all a bit handwavy for me, and I am not sure that my conclusions are correct. And if they are, in what degree.

Comment: How do you believe $\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}$ is defined in (a)? I think that's at the heart of the matter.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki x,y get infinitely close to the values of x0,y0 to a point, where they "might as well be" the same? Why, how should it be interpreted?

Comment: That's an intuition; that's not a definition. Intuition is always dangerous in circumstances like this; it's part of why formal definitions are so important. The one-dimensional limit is relatively easy to define, but two dimensions are a little trickier and you should try and figure out what a _precise_ definition for that notion is.